# Restrict SharePoint access for 1 ActiveDirectory group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, active-directory

I have a **SP 2016 farm** running for some time. The Users are synced with our **Active Directory**.
But now I have to restrict the use of our SharePoint to everyone except 1 **AD Group**.

What would the best approach be?

If you need further information, please ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Central Admin, Web application management, highlight the web application you'd like to restrict for a group. Select User Policy from the ribbon and type the group name and select "Deny All". Click finish and test.

[image]

As a test I added "All Users (windows)" to the denial policy, and my farm account, which is site collection admin also got an denial exception.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's no "deny" in SharePoint, except at the "global" Web application level, where you can deny access to users. This "technical" denial takes precendence over what's defined at the collection/sites levels.
So, one option for you would be to:

1. Grant access to all people you want everywhere in sites/lists/etc. as you usually do (this is what I call "functionnal permissions").
2. Go to the CA, and for the Web application deny access for users/groups you definitively want to restrict access for (see procedure [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608071.aspx) for example) (this is what I call "technical permissions"; that's the only place in SP you can deny access).